# Why does such a simple HDF5 example for file opening fail?

Tags: c, file, file-io, hdf5

I want to write a program to process and save data in HDF5 (the format, the original data is in).
To learn about `HDF5` I am playing with simple commands.
When I try to write data in the following snipped, I always get an error.

```c
#include <hdf5.h>

int main ( void )
{
        hid_t    file_id; dataset_id;
        herr_t   status;
        int      i, j, data[4][6];

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                data[i][j] = i * i * j;
        }
        
        file_id = H5Fopen ( "myfile.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT );
        dataset_id = H5Dopen ( file_id, "thatdset", H5P_DEFAULT );
       
        status = H5Dwrite ( dataset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INT,
                            H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, 
                            data);

        status = H5Dclose (dataset_id);
        status = H5Fclose (file_id);
}
```

I compile everything with clang on freebsd

```sh
cc myHDF5writer.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lhdf5 -g
```

And when I run it, I get the following error:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.6) thread 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 495 in H5Fopen(): invalid file open flags
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
...
```

When I try `fid = H5Fcreate ( FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);` instead of the `H5Fopen` call, I get what looks to me like a similar error:

```
...
  #000: H4D.c line 298 in H5Dopen2() unable to open dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Can't open object
...
```

Thanks for your help.
Edit: Typo.

Using the `H5F_ACC_RDWR` flagg in H5Fopen a file is created but with the following error:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.6) thread 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 509 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: H5Fint.c line 1498 in H5F_open(): unable to open file: time = Thu Dec 10 19:44:48 2020
, name = '/home/joengel/lecture/c/hdf5/nfile.h5', tent_flags = 1
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #002: H5FD.c line 734 in H5FD_open(): open failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: H5FDsec2.c line 346 in H5FD_sec2_open(): unable to open file: name = '/path/to/file.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 1, o_flags = 2
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.6) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 288 in H5Dopen2(): not a location
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
  #001: H5Gloc.c line 246 in H5G_loc(): invalid object ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.6) thread 0:
  #000: H5Dio.c line 314 in H5Dwrite(): dset_id is not a dataset ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.6) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 337 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.6) thread 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 671 in H5Fclose(): not a file ID
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Inappropriate type
```

Inspecting the file with `h5dump` yields `h5dump errro: unable to open file`

Comment: Have you tried supplying a full absolute path to the file?

Comment: As in a `#define FILE "/path/to/myfile.h5"`, yes I have.  That does not change anything.

Comment: What makes you think that the flags passed to `H5Fopen` are valid?  (This is a very different error, in that it wouldn't even *try* to open the file, whereas the call to `H5Fcreate` tried, but failed, to open the dataset.)

Comment: I would be very happy about suggestions for those flaggs. These flaggs are what I struggle with. I tried to become friends with the hdfgroups online resource. I probably still need to get on their train of thought.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_h5_file.html#ae20ef228e7c2db78d31180d3521319ee,

> Valid values of flags include: H5F_ACC_RDWR: Open with read/write access. If the file is currently open for read-only access then it will be reopened. Absence of this flag implies read-only access.
> H5F_ACC_RDONLY: Open with read only access. - default

Comment: Thank you for the awnser. This dose not cut it for me. As I understand the flaggs, both `H5F_ACC_RDWR` and `H5F_ACC_TRUNC` should allow my to write to a file. What did I miss?

Comment: What does "does not cut it" mean?  Did the flags cited in the documentation not work?

Comment: Following the documentation,  the examples provided do not work. That is why I moved here and reached out to you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I found my mistake.
What I wanted to do and did not do was to `H5Screate_simple(...)`